# How can I read the Haswell Uncore frequency from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, intel, frequency

I want to be able to read and if possible, change the uncore frequency for Haswell microarchitecture in Ubuntu 14.04. I know that CPU frequency can be changed by modifying values at /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/ but I am not able to find something equivalent for uncore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by John McCalpin at https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/543513, I did following to get the current uncore frequency:

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo wrmsr 0x391 0x20000000
sudo wrmsr 0x394 0x400000
sudo rdmsr 0x395 -d;sleep 1;sudo rdmsr 0x395 -d
```

First command loads the msr module. Second command set the bit 29 in  `MSR_UNC_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL` which enables all uncore counters. Third command sets bit 22 in `MSR_UNC_PERF_FIXED_CTRL` which enables fixed uncore counter. The output of the last command, gives me the uncore clock ticks in one second.